# Homology reference

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homology-cohomology

I want some references for homology of smooth projective variety.Is it exactly as homology in algebraic topology or it is different from it?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: The article by Lamtoke, "the topology of complex algebraic varieties after S. Lefschetz" is excellent.